# How do I rewrite this php code into jsp

Tags: php, jsp, url-rewriting

I try to rewrite the code into jsp but I could only do to the part where it test the code is connect to the database.

```
<?php
    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$connect) {
        die("Cannot connect to the server");
    }
    $db=mysql_select_db("payroll",$connect);
    if (!$db) {
        die("Cannot read the database");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['employee'])) {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM employee WHERE EMP_ID=\"".$_POST['employee']."\"");
        }
        header("Location:manage.php");
    }
?>
```

this is where I can translate to 
    <%
    User currentUser = null;
    Integer currentUserId = null;

```
if(session.getAttribute("name") == null) {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() +  "/normal/login.jsp?previousPageURL=user/edit_profile.jsp");
} else {

    currentUser = (name)session.getAttribute("name");
    currentUserId = currentname.getId();
}
```

%>

Comment: S.O is not a code translation service

Answer (score 0):

```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con; 
   con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/payroll", dbuser, dbpassword);
   PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM employee WHERE EMP_ID="+request.getParameter("employee"));
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
```